# What is the alternative to Bitmap so that I can store double/float values in it's pixels without casting to int/byte?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm creating a Bitmap from an array of doubles (for each pixel I am defining its color from the array). And because of the fact that the type Color can store only integer values(from 0 to 255) I have to cast my array values to int or byte before storing them into the color value for the Bitmap. But then, of course, I lose information because of the convertion. So I need some way to store my double values to representate the colors of the image somehow without any loss at all.

Update:
The problem is that Bitmap uses the type Color which needs integer numbers from a small range. It would be good to have a possibility to representante color in a double value form (like from 0 to 1) and store it in an image. But as far as I know Bitmap doesn't provide this opportunity.

Comment: What level of precision do you have in your doubles?
You could conceivably multiply by a factor of 10 to remove the decimal places and store that, then divide it back down when you need the information

Comment: @capncoolio, thank you, I liked the idea and I will now keep in mind that if such problem or similar occurs than there is such solution.
But I wasn't clear enough in my question (sorry, didn't think of that at first). By saying "I'm creating a Bitmap from an array of doubles" I mean that for each pixel I am defining its color from the double array. But the color's number representation should fit in 0-255 range. And multiplying by 10 will not make my double fit in Color type range. So unfortunately it won't work for me this situation. - Updating my question

Comment: A double is a 64 bit (8 byte) floating point number so you can use BitConvert to get the 8 bytes.

Comment: @jdweng, you mean the method BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits (Double)?
But the Color type askes for Int32.

Comment: Multiply the floating point values by 255

Comment: @DavidHeffernan , sorry, I didn't understand what should I do after multiplying and what advantage it will give me

Comment: You have floating point values in the range 0 to 1. But you need integer values in the range 0 to 255. So multiply the floating point values by 255 and round to nearest integer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan casting to int and rounding will give me a loss of information and that is what I'm avoiding

Comment: @TanyaK. Is your double some arbitrary-precision number between 0 and 1? If so, great, just multiply by 255 and drop the remainder (that should be close enough) otherwise, divide it down to be between 0 and 1 (by dividing the value by the upper bound) then do the above. You don't really have many other options, though there are 32-bit bitmaps you could play with to get 2^32-1 precision for the int

Comment: A single is a floating point number using 4 bytes, while a double is a floating point using 8 bytes.

Comment: You only lose information if you choose to. You don't have to throw away the floating point values. So don't. Keep them. When you need to create a bitmap for display, do so as described.

Comment: Of course, the other point to make is that you may think you have more information than you actually have. Yes your 64 bit doubles can store a lot of information, but if they are assigned with `(double)b / 255` where `b` is `byte` then you don't actually have any more information. It would be useful for us to know where this colour information actually came from.

Answer (score -1):

Let's see here:

If you want a single `double` to represent the RGB (and optionally A) fields of a pixel, you must separate out the respective bit ranges.

First, let's create an array of `double`s to represent our pixels (we have a static RNG called `_rand`):

```
double[,] vals = new double[500,500];

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
        vals[i, j] = _rand.NextDouble();
```

Next, let's create our bitmap:

```
Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(500,500);
```

Now what we want to do, is multiply each of those doubles by `int.MaxValue`, and separate the lower 8 bits out for `blue`, the middle-right 8 bits for `green`, the middle-left 8 bits for `red` and the top 8 bits for `alpha`. (We won't use the alpha for now)

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
    {
        var val = (int) (vals[i, j] * int.MaxValue);
        var b = (val & 0x000000FF);
        var g = (val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        var r = (val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        //var a = (val & 0xFF000000) >> 24; (this would get you the alpha)

        //Set the pixel at [i, j] to (r, g, b)
        bit.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
    }
}
```

That's about as precise as you'll get for a 32-bit bitmap. Each pixel is represented by a single 32-bit digit; not each colour of each pixel.

The complete program that'll produce a sample (random) output is as follows (I removed the part where we create and store the values in the `double[,]` and did the calculation straight:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace BitmapTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Random _rand = new Random();
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(500, 500);
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++)
                {
                    var val = (int)(_rand.NextDouble() * int.MaxValue);
                    var b = (val & 0x000000FF);
                    var g = (val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
                    var r = (val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
                    //var a = (val & 0xFF000000) >> 24; (this would get you the alpha)

                    bit.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(r, g, b));
                }
            }

            bit.Save(@"C:\Temp\img.bmp");
            bit.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, there is unfortunately no way to avoid loss of precision here, because bitmap pixel values must necessarily contain all their information within 32-bits (for a 32-bit bitmap obviously) and a `double` is already larger than that. If you wanted to store ARGB as 4 distinct, 64-bit `double`s, you'd need a 256-bit bitmap... Which, sure, could exist, but why?